# How do spark streaming on hive tables using sql in NON-real time?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

We have some data (millions) in hive tables which comes everyday. Next day, once the over-night ingestion is complete different applications query us for data (using sql)

We take this sql and make a call on spark

```
spark.sqlContext.sql(statement)  // hive-metastore integration is enabled
```

This is causing too much memory usage on spark driver, can we use spark streaming (or structured streaming), to **stream the results in a piped fashion** rather than collecting everything on driver and then sending to clients ?

We don't want to send out the data as soon it comes ( in typical streaming apps), but want to send a **streaming** data to clients when they ask (PULL) for data.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC..

- Spark Streaming is mainly designed to process streaming data by converting into batches of Milliseconds to Seconds.
- You can look over `streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long)` provides you a very good functionality for Spark to write
  Streaming processed output Sink in micro-batch manner.
- Nevertheless Spark structured streaming don't have a standard JDBC source defined to read from.
- Work out for an option to directly store Hive underlying files in compressed and structured manner, transfer them directly rather than selecting through spark.sql if every client needs same/similar data or partition them based on where condition of spark.sql query and transfer needed files further.

**Source:**

[Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#overview) queries are processed using a micro-batch processing engine, which processes data streams as a series of small batch jobs thereby achieving end-to-end latencies as low as 100 milliseconds and exactly-once fault-tolerance guarantees.

[ForeachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch):

foreachBatch(...) allows you to specify a function that is executed on the output data of every micro-batch of a streaming query. Since Spark 2.4, this is supported in Scala, Java and Python. It takes two parameters: a DataFrame or Dataset that has the output data of a micro-batch and the unique ID of the micro-batch.

Comment: what does ```IIUC``` mean ?

Comment: If I Understand Correctly